# servlet get ? instead unicode character(persian)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, unicode, utf-8

i have a very simple html with a submit button and a textbox that send a unicode (persian) text to servlet and run it on weblogic. I set charset=UTF-8 in jsp page and request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); in servlet but when I get parameter from request and print it or insert it into database it is ???
I use  URLDecoder too but it didn’t help. how could I fix this?
the html code:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
     <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
        <fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" /> 
        <form method="get" action="main"> 
        <input type="submit" name="search"  value="جستجو" >
        <input type="text" name="keyWord" class="bodyfont" >
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

the servlet code:

```
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String input =   URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("keyWord"), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("keyWord"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String input =   URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("keyWord"), "UTF-8");
```

The parameter is already URL-decoded for you by `getParameter`, so the outer `URLDecoder.decode()` call does nothing (except for potentially corrupt any actual percent signs in the real value).

The encoding used by `getParameter` when it calls `URLDecoder` internally is ISO-8859-1; the call to `request.setCharacterEncoding` above does not affect query string decoding. (It only affects POSTed forms, and even then that usually doesn't work unless you're calling it in a filter.)

There are three options to work around this extreme lameness in the Servlet spec:

1. container-specific options to configure a different query string encoding, such as `<Connector URIEncoding>` in Tomcat, or `<java-charset-name>` in Weblogic;
2. accept that the parameter has been mis-decoded, and mis-encode it back the other way: `new String(request.getParameter("foo").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8")`;
3. grab `request.getQueryString()` and parse it into separate parameters yourself, then URLDecode using the correct encoding from the start. This is more work, but at least you can make your app run consistently in environments where people have done (1).

> `System.out.println(input);`

This is troublesome in itself. The terminal might not support Unicode (especially under Windows), or Java might not have set its default encoding correctly. If Java thinks `System.out` is an ASCII or ISO-8859-1 then it won't be able to print any Persian so you would get `?`. It's common for Java to fail to detect terminal encoding and plump for ASCII.

The default can be overridden with `-Dfile.encoding=...`, but this is annoying to set for the whole container. If you're sure that your terminal does support UTF-8 you could try encoding to UTF-8 bytes manually with `getBytes` and `System.out.write` them, or create a new PrintStream over `System.out` using UTF-8 as the encoding.

Comment: i test all 3 approach but still print ????, i test post and setCharacterEncoding in Filter. :(

Comment: Added notes re System.out.

Comment: thanks so much. it works. i check terminal in stand alone java programs, but here it isn't able to print persian. i use a jsp file to test request parameters and it print it right. thank you again :)